# Unable to edit eclipse.ini file on Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7

I have eclipse Galileo installed in following location - C:\Program Files (x86)
I was getting a weird error while executing Selenium tests on IE 8 browser.
As soon as browser is launched I encounter error -

```
RunTimeError -

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\javaw.exe

The application has requested run time to terminate it in unusual way....
```

Following this I found that a few encountered this error and got rid of it by increasing jvm heap in eclipse.ini file

And I tried doing same. I am able to edit eclipse.ini file but as soon as I save it encounter error about "Access Denied". I have admin rights on the Windows 7 machine

Comment: Did you open the editor as administrator?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That is because of window7 security issue :D

Go to search programe and files  --Type notepad  when it come right click on notepad and "run as administrator"

it will open notepad with administrator rights now use file->open in notepad navigate to your eclipse .ini file make changes and save it  :)

[image: Screen Shot ![enter image description here]

Comment: A picture is worth thousand words :)

Answer (score 2):

Or copy eclipse.ini to your favorite location. Create a new shortcut for eclipse. In target, add the following parameter

```
"C:\Program Files\Eclipse\eclipse.exe" eclipse --launcher.ini C:\favorite\eclipse.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty fix: Copy the eclipse.ini file to a location where you don't need admin rights (i.e., desktop), edit it, then overwrite the old file with the updated one from your desktop.