# Unable to save changes in Eclipes .java and .xml files

Tags: java, android, eclipse, windows-7

Recently I freshly installed eclipse and copied workspace containing from other computer into this computer containing fresh install of eclipse.
Eclipse version is same as before.

I imported the projects in eclipse.
Now when I try to make changes or edit `.java` or `.xml` file, I can't save changes in them and hence can't compile them. I get error of `ACCESS DENIED`!

What should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: check file permissions , is all I can advise

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Eclipse and projects aren't is `C:\Program Files...`, or you would need to launch Eclipse as an Administrator in order to have the right to modify files in it.

See "[Unable to edit eclipe.ini file on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231844/unable-to-edit-eclipe-ini-file-on-windows-7)" as an illustration.

Comment: nope they are not. They are in default directory i-e; User/yourcomputername.

Comment: @AlfredJames is it under Documents (as in http://superuser.com/questions/404317/unable-to-copy-files-from-protected-folders)?

Answer (score 0):

File permissions or restarting Eclipse. That happened to me once.